# Django filter based on average of a field in reverse foreignkey

Tags: django, django-filter

I have 2 classes, Product and Rating.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', default = 'img/no-img.png')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default = (randint(0,1000000)))

    def get_avg_rating(self):
        avg_rating = self.rate_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))
        if avg_rating['rating__avg']:
            return round(avg_rating['rating__avg'],1)
        else:
            return 0

class Rate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default=Decimal(0.0))
```

I'm trying to get the average ratings between two numbers, I have tried:

```
Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=search, rate__rating__lte=rating[0], rate__rating__gte=rating[1])
```

The above didn't pick up any results from the database. The value of rating list is `['0', '6']`, I have an object in the database with average rating of 2. The object isn't returned, and I get no errors. Is it possible to query the above at the database level, or should I do it in python?

Comment: What is the point of the `get_avg_rating` method? Where is it being called from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry for the late reply. I use get_avg_rating in the template: `{{ product.get_avg_decimal_rating }}`, is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to annotate average rating and filter queryset by result:

```
Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=search).annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rate__rating')).filter(avg_rating__lte=rating[0], avg_rating__gte=rating[1])
```

Comment: I might be getting something else wrong, does the comparison matter in this case? rating is a string that is passed on from the template, and the rating field is decimal. I tried Decimal(rating[0]) and I'm still getting no returns.

Comment: @almostabeginner if your ratings is `[0, 6]` then it should be `avg_rating__gte=rating[0], avg_rating__lte=rating[1]`. Swap `lte` and `gte`. It means less then and greater then.